# How can I populate a class from the results of a SQL query in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, orm

I've got a class like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; private set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public decimal Price { get; private set; }
    public int Stock { get; private set; }
    public int PendingStock { get; private set; }
}
```

I can fetch those details from my database like this:

```
SELECT product_id, supplier_id, name, price, total_stock, pending_stock 
FROM products
WHERE product_id = ?
```

I don't want to have to manually run through a `DataSet` or `DataTable` to set the values.

I'm sure there's a way to populate the class using some kind of binding / mapping mechanism, but the only stuff I could find was for binding to winforms components or using XAML.

Is there some kind of attribute I can apply to my properties / class to have the class automatically populated from a query row?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've decided to propose another answer, which actually extension to the answer provided by Alex (so all credits to him), but it introduces attributes for the sake of column-name-2-property-name mapping.

First of all custom attribute to hold column name is needed:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]
[Serializable]
public class MappingAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ColumnName = null;
}
```

The attribute must be applied to those properties of the class, that are to be populated from database row:

```
public class Product
{
    [Mapping(ColumnName = "product_id")]
    public int ProductId { get; private set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "supplier_id")]
    public int SupplierId { get; private set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    [Mapping(ColumnName = "price")]
    public decimal Price { get; private set; }
    [Mapping(ColumnName = "total_stock")]
    public int Stock { get; private set; }
    [Mapping(ColumnName = "pending_stock")]
    public int PendingStock { get; private set; }
}
```

And rest goes as Alex proposed, except that the attribute is used to retrieve column name:

```
T MapToClass<T>(SqlDataReader reader) where T : class
{
        T returnedObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        PropertyInfo[] modelProperties = returnedObject.GetType().GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i < modelProperties.Length; i++)
        {
            MappingAttribute[] attributes = modelProperties[i].GetCustomAttributes<MappingAttribute>(true).ToArray();

            if (attributes.Length > 0 && attributes[0].ColumnName != null)
                modelProperties[i].SetValue(returnedObject, Convert.ChangeType(reader[attributes[0].ColumnName], modelProperties[i].PropertyType), null);
        }
        return returnedObject;
}
```

Comment: I ended up writing almost exactly this. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Just remember that reflection is not free, so a little bit of caching might be necessary when mapping more than a few lines ;)

Comment: I totally agree with madd0 (I stated the same in my other answer). If you wish to use the code excessively - you would need to provide some caching.

Comment: Yeah, I'm providing a mechanism to store the attributes in a cache to save on reflection costs.

Comment: NB if you are having a problem with the `ToArray()` call in a CLR project, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549579/using-system-linq-assembly-in-sql-clr-udf

Answer (score 14):

You need to either map the properties yourself or use an ORM (Object relational mapper).

Microsoft provides [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx), but [Dapper](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net) requires less overhead and might be a viable option depending on your requirements.

In your case, the Dapper code would look something like:

```
var query = @"SELECT product_id, supplier_id, name, price, total_stock, pending_stock 
FROM products
WHERE product_id = @id";

var product = connection.Query<Product>(query, new { id = 23 });
```

For the sake of completeness, it's important to point out that I'm talking about Dapper here because the question concerns mapping SQL results to objects. EF and Linq to SQL will do this too, but they will also do additional stuff, like translating Linq queries into SQL statements, which might also be useful.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to leverage an ORM framework (Entity Framework etc.) you can do it by hand:

```
T MapToClass<T>(SqlDataReader reader) where T : class
{
        T returnedObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        List<PropertyInfo> modelProperties = returnedObject.GetType().GetProperties().OrderBy(p => p.MetadataToken).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < modelProperties.Count; i++)
            modelProperties[i].SetValue(returnedObject, Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetValue(i), modelProperties[i].PropertyType), null);
        return returnedObject;
}
```

you use it like this:

```
Product P = new Product(); // as per your example
using(SqlDataReader reader = ...)
{
while(reader.Read()) { P = MapToClass<Product(reader); /* then you use P */ }
}
```

Only thing to take care of, is the order of the fields in the query (it MUST match the order of the properties as they are defined in your class).

All you need to do is build the class, write a query, then it will take care of the "mapping".

**WARNING** I use this method a lot and never had any issue, but **it doesn't work properly for partial classes**. If you come to partial models you're much better off using an ORM framework anyway.

Comment: Alex, this is wrong. GetProperties() do not guarantee that returned PropertyInfo objects are in order of declaration.

Comment: I use this method *a lot* and they always turn up in the right way... Enforcing the order is quite easy anyway, I'll take the chance to update the code.

Comment: I do it too ;] but documentation is clear on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb How are you going to enforce order if you have no mapper of column-name-2-property-name?

Comment: There you go, just order them by metadatatoken (I actually left it out because I didn't copy paste the code from the latest version of my toolbox).

Comment: Alex, ordering by metadatatoken is another assumption without documentation background. :] I'd recommend for a complete solution using custom attributes on properties to describe either order of columns or a column name that property should get data from.

Comment: I honestly never encountered any issue with this approach (and I use it to handle quite heavy data). There is one prominent caveat I forgot though, I updated my answer.

Comment: Why not just retrieve data by column name?  `reader[modelProperties[i].Name]`

Comment: Things get mixed up when the class is partial, probably due to how the composing of the properties is handled by the compiler. I faced this issue a couple of times. Retrieving data by column name is a good suggestion, *if* they have the same name... Which is usually not my scenario.

Comment: Alex, I decided to extend your answer to avoid order-related problems and partial classes exclusion.

Comment: +1 Andomar's comment as it reflects a popular rule of DRY - life is much easier when class fields are the same as table columns (though it's not always possible).

Answer (score 2):

I would use Linq to SQL and do it as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; private set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public decimal Price { get; private set; }
    public int Stock { get; private set; }
    public int PendingStock { get; private set; }

    public Product(int id)
    {
        using(var db = new MainContext())
        {
            var q = (from c in product where c.ProductID = id select c).SingleOrDefault();
            if(q!=null)
                LoadByRec(q);           
        }
    }
    public Product(product rec)
    {
        LoadByRec(q);
    }
    public void LoadByRec(product rec)
    {
        ProductId = rec.product_id;
        SupplierID = rec.supplier_id;
        Name = rec.name;
        Price = rec.price;
        Stock = rec.total_stock;
        PendingStock = rec.pending_stock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to this? I don't see `db` being used anywhere in the `using`, and there's no reference to the query. Is there no way to have `LoadByRec` work as a set of attributes rather than manually mapping them across in a method?

Comment: @Poly you have to insert a data context: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384470.aspx which in this case you would name `MainContext`.  Definitely play around with it, it's really really powerful and a huge timesaver

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality by default in raw .NET Framework. You could use Entity Framework, but if it's not a good solution for you, then an alternative would be reflection mechanism.

1. Create some custom attribute class that can hold a column name for each public property of your class.
2. After retrieving record from database instantiate an object of `Product` class and enumerate properties. For each property that has you custom attribute - use `SetValue` of `PropertyInfo` to change value according to column name defined in custom attribute.

Take the following into consideration:

- the solution is quite and overhead to simple assignments; it only makes sense if you have many tables and many classes like `Product` - and wish to write one code to automatically initialize all of them
- reflection is an overhead itself - so some caching would be required in the long run

Comment: This sounds interesting. I'll take a look into it. Also, how could I *not* upvote an answer from a guy with *L* as his avatar!? :)

Comment: Thanks. :] Please look at Alex's anwer here, as he has provided code for what I proposed here, so his answer is much better *except* that I'd highly recommend using custom attributes on your `Product` class' fields.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking into it now. Cheers :)

Comment: Please look at my another answer that extends Alex solution with custom attributes.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

In SQL query you can use ["PATH Mode with FOR XML "](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510462.aspx) clause.

The result of the query will be an XML, which you can [deserialize directly to C# objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257746/deserialize-xml).

It also works very well on large nested SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should be using Entity Framework or Linq To SQL and if you dont want to use that, then you need to map/fill it yr self

more info on Entity Framework
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

more info on Linq to SQL
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx

Comment: Could you provide a quick example for the entity framework? I've flicked through the documentation, but it's very vague on how you actually use it.

Comment: The problem is that the class has to be created from entity, you can't use your own classes for that, and from my knowledge there's no automatic way of converting unless manual mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Using Entity Framework you could use the SqlQuery method to populate a class that is not a table or view:
context.Database.SqlQuery(sql, parameterList)

Offcourse you need to use EF. :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
select 'public ' + case DATA_TYPE  
when 'varchar' then 'string'
when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
when 'DateTime' then 'DateTime'
when 'bigint' then 'long' 
else DATA_TYPE end +' '+ COLUMN_NAME + ' {get; set;}' 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE TABLE_NAME ='YOUR TABLE NAME'  ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.